# How to extract N-level object from JSON string

Tags: python, json

I want to extract `wind` object's data from the following JSON string:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

request=Request('...')
response_weather = urlopen(request)
w = response_weather.read()
metar = json.loads(w)
wind = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(metar['wind']))
print wind


KeyError: 'wind'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to extract `wind` object's data

Then you want you want `metar['conditions']['wind']`

And based on your screenshot, that key contains the following object: `{direction: 60, directionIsVariable: false, speedKnots: "3.00"}`

<sub>P.S. Since that's a single object, I'm not sure what you want to achieve by making it into a `pandas.DataFrame`</sub>

Comment: I am appending pandas DataFrame with more readings of `wind` obtained from other requests

Answer (score 1):

To get to the `wind` object, you first have to get the `conditions` object out of `metar`. Once you have the `conditions` object, you can then pull out the `wind` object.

`Metar` doesn't have a `wind` child, so `metar['wind']` doesn't access anything. `metar['conditions']` will work, because there is a `conditions child`.

Hope that helps!